# Bokeh Table: Horizontal ScrollBar hiding last line

Tags: bokeh

I would like to be able to remove the horizontal scrollbar from the bokeh table or at least push it down so it does not hide the last row on the table.

[image]

As showed on the picture, I cannot read the last row. The vertical scrollbar cannot go further down.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue. Are you using Google Chrome by chance?
If I use Google Chrome I have this problem and can't get rid of the horizontal scrollbar for the life of me.

But with Firefox the scrollbar is gone if you pass `fit_columns=True`  to your DataTable() call. Or `fit_columns=False` if you want the scrollbar to show up. Ironically under Firefox if the scrollbar shows up it does not block off the bottom row.

Comment: Man ... I can't remember anymore but I was using Safari I believe.